# AmazonS3ClientBuilder is stuck on build function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the code suggested on amazon documentation for uploading files to amazon buckets. The code is running on some machines, but on others, it doesn't pass the build() line.

Here is the code:

```
private static AWSBucketManager instance = null; 
    private final AmazonS3 s3;
    private String clientRegion= Settings.getSettingValue("AWS_REGION");
    private String secretKey = Settings.getSettingValue("AWS_SECRETKEY");
    private String accesssKey = Settings.getSettingValue("AWS_ACCESSKEY");
    private AWSBucketManager()
    {   
        LoggingService.writeToLog("Login to aws bucket with basic creds",LogModule.Gateway, LogLevel.Info);
        BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesssKey, secretKey);         
        LoggingService.writeToLog("Success Login to aws bucket with basic creds",LogModule.Gateway, LogLevel.Info);
        s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
                .build();
        LoggingService.writeToLog("Login successfully to aws bucket with basic creds",LogModule.Gateway, LogLevel.Info);
    }
    
    public static AWSBucketManager getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new AWSBucketManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

any idea what is going wrong? or how I can debug it with logs?

Comment: "doesn't pass the build() line" - this is not enough information to give you any kind of help. What error do you get at the build line on those machines? Do those machines have credentials for AWS?

Comment: That's the point. I don't get an error. it is stuck on the build command forever. And yes, the machines has credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem occurred because my code is obfuscated with proguard.
adding the following rules solved this issue:

-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**               { *; }
-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*

-keep class com.amazonaws.** { *; }